# How to replace modules at compile time in go

Tags: go

I am writing a integration test suite (`test-suite`) for applications (`app`). The test-suite is it's own module, as it is used for more apps. The apps just `require github.com/.../test-suite/` and use it in their tests.

One of the requirements that the test-suite tests is running in a Docker container.

When I am developing the test suite, I work on it in a local folder and have a replace directive in go.mod `replace github.com/.../test-suite/ ../test-suite/`. So far, so good.

But when the tests try to run the app within a Docker container, the build fails, because there is no such thing as `../test-suite/` in the container.

How to approach that?

Is there something like `GOFLAGS='-replace=github.com/.../test-suite=../test-suite/'` (no, that doesn't work)

I've tried also copying that directory in the Dockerfile, but the app runs in root there, so no `../test-suite/" is able to be there.

Comment: It sounds like you need to re-visit your test execution process, not work around the Go tools.

Comment: @JonathanHall I thought about that a lot as well. Do you have any suggestions how to test the app's own ability to run in a Docker container? Testing for correct Dockerfile, all services being available in the container ...)

Comment: The answer to your questions is "No." You have to redesign.

Comment: Can you not just point the replace at "mylaptop" with the appropriate SSH/firewall settings? So the same "path" works from either?